# Dynamically changing in-line CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue where this error occurs: `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

I am using a color picker to change the CSS of of one of my components dynamically, so every time the color changes, it cause a re-render, which I believe is the reason the error is occurring. Below is an example of what would cause the error:

```
const card = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState('#FFF')

    return (
      <>
        <Box sx={{backgroundColor: color}}>
           some content
        </Box>
        
        <ColorPicker
           value={color}
           onChange={setColor}
        />
     </>
    )
}
```

The specific color picker I am using is this one: [react-gradient-color-picker](https://github.com/hxf31891/react-gradient-color-picker). Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: The error "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded" occurs when a component is re-rendering itself too many times in a row. This can happen if a component updates its own state, which then causes it to re-render, and then it updates its state again, and so on. This can create an infinite loop of updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuous hovering over the colors to choose the desired color from the color picker leads to many state changes  and, correspondingly, triggers the warning: 'Maximum update depth exceeded.

Use debounce and useCallback hook

```
  import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
  const debouncedSetColor = use callback(
    debounce((newColor) => {
      setColor(newColor);
    }, 300), // Adjust the debounce delay
    []
  );

  const handleColorChange = (newColor) => {
    debouncedSetColor(newColor);
  };


  <ColorPicker value={color} onChange={handleColorChange}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you've imported the wrong component. The code you provided should work just right.

```
import ColorPicker from "react-best-gradient-color-picker";
```

It's also possible that the Box component is the cause of the error message, so perhaps try to pass the style object as React `CSS Properties`, rather than through the `SX` Prop:

```
<Box style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>{content}</Box>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the component you're importing here has built-in debounce?